# Is there an adapter for Canon AE-1 lenses on Canon 550D?

Tags: lens, old-lenses, lens-mount, lens-adapter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it worth it to buy an FD-EOS adapter, or is it better to exchange a misbought lens?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/7172/is-it-worth-it-to-buy-an-fd-eos-adapter-or-is-it-better-to-exchange-a-misbought)

Is there a way to use my old [Canon AE-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_AE-1) lenses on my new [EOS-550D](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_EOS_550D)?