# Can you mount lenses from a Canon T70 on an EOS 550D body?

Tags: lens

Sometime ago, I was fortunate enough to have been given a Canon T70 35mm and several lenses.  I've now just bought myself an EOS 550D (T2i) and wanted to know if anyone has any experience of reasonably priced lens adaptors? If so, which ones are recommended...

I've also got a Paragon 500mm F8.0 Telephoto lens which has a screw fixing on the end as opposed to the 'usual' lugs.  Is it possible to get an adaptor for this also?

Pics of lens added as requested :)

[image: Whole lens]
<sub>(source: [andyguyett.co.uk](http://www.andyguyett.co.uk/images/camera/lens1.jpg))</sub>

[image: Lens front]
<sub>(source: [andyguyett.co.uk](http://www.andyguyett.co.uk/images/camera/lens2.jpg))</sub>

[image: Lens back]
<sub>(source: [andyguyett.co.uk](http://www.andyguyett.co.uk/images/camera/lens3.jpg))</sub>

[image: Measurement]
<sub>(source: [andyguyett.co.uk](http://www.andyguyett.co.uk/images/camera/lens4.jpg))</sub>

Hope that worked :)

Answer (score 2):

Short: Do not do that!

More in detail: 
FD requires an adapter. If this adapter has no additional optics then you will not be able to focus on infinity and not from a certain distance. You can use the lens in macro areas though.

Adapters with a lens overcome this shortage for the price of a significant loss in optical quality.

Better go for M42 lenses on EOS bodies. Your 500mm with the "screw" coudl be a candidate. It could as well be a T2 mount, which can be perfectly adopted.

Answer (score 1):

Your paragon 500mm lens have m42 adapter and its 100% useable on Canon 550D, because I am use the same one on Canon 60D. Just purchase a M42 to Eos adapter, its very cheap for 2$ approx. This lens will definately work on your Canon 550D camera.

Hope this helped you.

Answer (score 0):

The T70 uses the older [FD mount](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FD_mount), and unless the lenses are *very* nice, it's generally not worth trying to adapt [FD lenses for the newer EF mount](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/7172/is-it-worth-it-to-buy-an-fd-eos-adapter-or-is-it-better-to-exchange-a-misbought).

As for the Paragon lens, you'd need to know more about exactly which mount it uses. Hopefully someone can provide that information from your pictures.

Comment: Thanks Philip - I'll grab a couple of pics which I hope will be of some use.....  :)