# Can I use a Canon FD lens with a T6/1300D?

Tags: lens, canon, lens-adapter

I am currently using a Canon T6/1300D. Earlier today got the Canon FD 28mm f/2.8 in the mail and my adapter. However, whenever I try using the camera with this lens it says `F00` and everything is out of focus.

It will focus manually only when I'm within 2 inches of what I'm shooting, but other than that, no matter how I dial the focus ring, it won't work.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: It will only when I'm with in 2 inches of what I'm shooting, but other then that no matter were on the focus ring I am it won't work @dav1dsm1th

Answer (score 2):

Your camera is displaying F00 because it has no idea what aperture the lens is using. The FD lenses don't have any circuitry or electrical contacts, to my knowledge.

So, you will not be able to have your camera set the aperture. You'll need to shoot on M and set the shutter speed via camera, and aperture via the lens.

You'll also need to focus manually.

[See this question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/7172/is-it-worth-it-to-buy-an-fd-eos-adapter-or-is-it-better-to-exchange-a-misbought) on the hard reality of adapting FD to EOS.

> It will only when I'm with in 2 inches of what I'm shooting, but other then that no matter were on the focus ring I am it won't work

Adapting FD to EOS means using an adapter that has an element in it - this element tweaks things a bit but ultimately allows you to focus. If your adapter does not have an element in it, then it is effectively acting like an extension tube. Per the laws of the tube - your focus range will be drastically affected.

Comment: "So, you will not be able to have your camera set the aperture. You'll need to shoot on M and set the shutter speed via camera, and aperture via the lens" the thing is I normally on shoot Manual and the shots I have taken have been, it still is out of focus and not working

Comment: @eduardkarpoev - which adapter did you buy?

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the focusing mechanism of your 28/2.8 is broken. The price of a vintage used lens may seem low, but you should always budget for a [CLA](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/15613/what-is-cla-service) and consider the possibly of a repair. A lot of eBay sellers know less about lenses than their buyers do, and descriptions can be misleading.

What you're experiencing could also be normal behavior for adapting an FD/FL-mount lens to a Canon EOS camera with a simple ring adapter.

The mount depth of the FD/FL mount was shallower than the current EOS mount, so adding the lens onto the camera with a ring adapter is acting like an macro extension tube.  You lose the ability to focus to infinity, and the entire focus range is much closer to the camera. Although, typically, this will be a few feet, not two inches.  This might not be an issue with macro shooters adapting macro lenses or portrait shooters using portrait lenses, which is why those simple adapter rings are sold.

There are other adapter rings, with a glass element to act as a short teleconverter, which can restore focus to infinity. But the tradeoff is that if you got a cheap adapter, the glass element typically isn't of the highest quality, so not only have you increased the focal length and reduced the max. aperture (as teleconverters do), you've also added softness to your lens.

In addition, unless the adapter has been equipped with a chip, it doesn't electronically communicate with your camera.  So you can only manually focus, there's no controlling the aperture from the camera body (only through the aperture ring on the lens), and your camera has to do stop-down metering for the metering to be accurate (Canon dSLRs do, so that's okay. Less fun if you're an entry-level Nikon shooter with a D3x00 or D5x00 body). You'll also be missing the lens EXIF information (e.g., focal length, aperture setting used, etc.)

This is why FD lenses are so cheap on the used market. They can only really be used with simple ring adapters on mirrorless cameras.

The six film SLR mounts you *can* adapt to Canon EOS with simple ring adapters would be: Leica R, Contax/Yashica, Olympus OM, Nikon F, Pentax K, and M42. And they're likely more expensive as a result of having more competition for them because of this.

See also: [Can I use lens brand X on interchangeable lens camera brand Y?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/62000)