# Can a non-AF lens be used on a Canon 1000D AF camera?

Tags: lens

Can I use a non-AF lens with a Canon 1000D AF body. Canon lenses use in-lens motors for focus, and the only connection is electrical, so I don't see why not. What type of mount and lens should I look for? I like the convenience of AF, but there are times when I don't need it, and non-AF lens are cheaper.

Comment: To be clear: If you mean Canon "FD bayonet" or "breech lock" lenses when you say "non-AF", these are *just as foreign-mount a lens to an EF mount camera than any other foreign-mount lens*. https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/7172/is-it-worth-it-to-buy-an-fd-eos-adapter-or-is-it-better-to-exchange-a-misbought . However, a *manual focus lens that comes with an EF mount* will, of course, work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- AF = Auto Focus; MF = Manual Focus

  If by non-AF lens, you meant a manual-focus lens, the answer is yes. **You can use manual-focus lenses with your camera.** Depending on the particular lens you are interested in, you may need an adapter.
- EF = "[Electro-Focus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_EF_lens_mount)". This is the name of the Canon mount.

  If you meant to type non-EF lens, the answer is also yes. **You can use adapters to attach non-EF manual-focus lenses to your camera.** For instance, adapters are available for M42 lenses. However, there are limits on which lenses you can use. See [Can I use lens brand X on interchangeable lens camera brand Y?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/62000/75526)

To get an idea of what lenses and adapters are available, you can search for "EF lens" and "EF adapter" on various shopping sites. However, be aware that **"Using an adapter most of the time is masochism."**, [as Agent_L has commented](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/98887/75526#comment182493_98887).

Unless you are after a specific effect, such as fish-eye or particular bokeh, you would be better served by getting a modern general-purpose lens, such as the EF-S 18-135mm/F3.5-5.6 IS USM, which is fairly inexpensive. Despite being a zoom lens, it will deliver much better image quality than most adapted manual-focus lenses.

---

As [noted by Frank](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/100489/75526#comment187075_100490), your camera has a crop-frame sensor and [EF-S mount](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_EF-S_lens_mount). Lenses with [EF mounts](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/62000/75526), made for use with full-frame sensors, will work with your camera. EF-S lenses made by Canon can be identified by an extra ring of plastic that prevents them from being mounted on full-frame bodies. However, EF-S lenses made by third parties may still mount on full-frame bodies. In this case, they may be identified by heavy vignetting in the images taken with them. Care should be taken to ensure that lens elements do not obstruct and damage the mirror.

[image: EF-S Mount]
[image: EF Mount]

Comment: There are two types of lens mounts that will fit your camera without the need of an adapter.  These are the EF-S and EF lens mounts.  The EF mount is compatible with any Canon DSLR or AF SLR.  The EF-S mount is different in that these lenses will only fit onto Canon APS-C format DSLRs; it is literally impossible to attach an EF-S lens onto a full-frame DSLR or SLR.  There are some lenses like those from Samyang that have an EF or EF-S lens mount, but they don't have the internal AF motor.  They will work just like any other lens, but without AF.